# C# compiler can't find interface Extension Method?

Tags: c#

I have an interface:

```
public interface: IA { ... }
```

and I try to extend it into

```
class public A : IA {
    private static void foo(this IA a) {
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

but compiler says, that it can't find foo(), with first parameter of type IA.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you marked your extension class as static as well? i.e. The class with the extension method must be marked as static AND the extension method itself must also be static.

```
 public static class AExtensions : IA 
 {
     public static void foo(this IA a) { a.foo(); } 
 }
```

Comment: your method must also be public. i.e.

Comment: public static class AExtensions : IA {
        public static void foo(this IA a) {
            a.foo();
        }
    }

Comment: thanks. this works with private too. now i have another error). Thank you very much))

Comment: +1. @BlackSpy, it is better to edit your answer instead of providing code in comments...

Comment: Thanks Alexei - First day answering questions on SO - learning as I go along